# Rotate Image Gtk 3 with cairo

Tags: gtk3, cairo

Im trying to get a image at random location to rotate. I was looking at another similar post([rotate image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10986142/how-to-rotate-image-using-gtk-cairo?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)). But I couldn't get things to work.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <cairo.h>

GtkWidget *window;

static void rotate_cb()
{
    gtk_widget_queue_draw(window);

}

static gboolean on_expose_event(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventExpose *event, gpointer data)
{
    GtkWidget *img = (GtkWidget *)(data);
    gint w = gtk_widget_get_allocated_width (img);
    gint h = gtk_widget_get_allocated_height (img);
    gtk_widget_realize(img);
    cairo_surface_t *surface = gdk_window_create_similar_surface(gtk_widget_get_window (img), CAIRO_CONTENT_COLOR, w, h);
    cairo_t *cr = cairo_create (surface);

    cairo_translate(cr, w/2, h/2);
    cairo_rotate(cr, 2);
    cairo_set_source_surface(cr, surface, -w/2, -h/2);

    cairo_paint(cr);
    cairo_destroy(cr);
    cairo_surface_destroy(surface);
    return FALSE;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 600, 600);
    gtk_widget_set_app_paintable(window, TRUE);
    GtkWidget *l = gtk_layout_new(NULL, NULL);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), l);
    GtkWidget *img = gtk_image_new_from_file("example.png");
    gtk_layout_put(GTK_LAYOUT(l), img, 300, 300);

    g_signal_connect(window, "draw", G_CALLBACK (on_expose_event), img);
    g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    GtkWidget *button = gtk_button_new_with_label("button");
    g_signal_connect(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(rotate_cb), NULL);
    gtk_layout_put(GTK_LAYOUT(l), button, 0, 0);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main();
}
```

The window does received the draw signal, but I didn't know how to connect gtkwidget and cairo_surface_t.

Or maybe there are better ways of doing this(without cairo). I prefer all kinds of ideas! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GtkWidget `draw` signal handler prototype should be:

```
gboolean user_function (GtkWidget *widget, CairoContext *cr, gpointer user_data)
```

as described in the [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-draw):

> This signal is emitted when a widget is supposed to render itself. The
>   widget 's top left corner must be painted at the origin of the passed
>   in context and be sized to the values returned by
>   gtk_widget_get_allocated_width() and
>   gtk_widget_get_allocated_height().
>
> Signal handlers connected to this signal can modify the cairo context
>   passed as cr in any way they like and don't need to restore it. The
>   signal emission takes care of calling cairo_save() before and
>   cairo_restore() after invoking the handler.
>
> The signal handler will get a cr with a clip region already set to the
>   widget's dirty region, i.e. to the area that needs repainting.
>   Complicated widgets that want to avoid redrawing themselves completely
>   can get the full extents of the clip region with
>   gdk_cairo_get_clip_rectangle(), or they can get a finer-grained
>   representation of the dirty region with
>   cairo_copy_clip_rectangle_list(). Parameters
>
> widget - the object which received the signal
>
> cr - the cairo context to draw to
>
> user_data - user data set when the signal handler was connected.

So your `on_expose_event` function prototype must change and the cairo context will be provided to you:

```
static gboolean on_expose_event(GtkWidget *widget, cairo_t *cr, gpointer data)
{
.... // your code must change too
}
```

Comment: So in this case, would I be creating a cairo surface over the whole window or only the widget I want to rotate?

Comment: It would return the cairo context of the widget you connected the signal to, if it has a GdkWindow

Comment: @AndrewShao you don't need to create one... the callback gives you one to work with

Comment: using the one from GtkWindow is not the best option, e.g. use a GtkDrawingArea.

Comment: Thanks ! Ill try !